# Como hago para calcular una combinación ganadora en Primitiva (Java)?

Tags: java

Necesito saber como puedo calcular una combinación ganadora en Java es en la Primitiva

El código que os muestro aqui , es lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora , necesito ayuda para poder calcular la combinación ganadora , ya que me está costando mucho entenderlo y poder realizarlo , Estuve haciendolo por mi mismo, Si alguien puede ayudarme , Lo agradeceria mucho

La clase donde es en CalcularCombinaciónGanadora  es esa parte que no se hacer

```
public void init(){
    System.out.println("***** PRIMITIVA ******");

    int[] apuesta = introducirApuesta();

    int[] combinacionGanadora = calcularCombinacionGanadora();

    if (combinacionGanadora!=null) {
        System.out.println("La combinacion ganadora es: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < combinacionGanadora.length - 1; i++) {
            System.out.print(combinacionGanadora[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("Reintegro: " + combinacionGanadora[combinacionGanadora.length - 1]);
    }

    int premio = comprobarAciertos(apuesta, combinacionGanadora);
    System.out.println("Tu premio es: "+premio+" €");

}

public int[] introducirApuesta(){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int random=(int)(Math.random()*0+9);
    System.out.println("Introduce tu apuesta");
    int [] apuesta=new int[7];
    for (int i=0;i<apuesta.length;i++){
        apuesta[i]=input.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("La Apuesta introducida es");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(apuesta)+" "+random);

    return apuesta;
}

public int[] calcularCombinacionGanadora(){
   int [] combinacion=new int[7];
        Random rnd=new Random();


    return combinacion;
}
```

Comment: 1) ¿Qué es una combinación ganadora? 2) `int random=(int)(Math.random()*0+9);` Esto siempre dará nueve porque todo numero multiplcado por cero es cero.

Comment: Qué es Primitiva? En programación, un tipo de dato primitivo es una cosa pero dudo que te refieras a eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, estoy de acuerdo con uno de los comentarios,

```
int random=(int)(Math.random()*0+9);
```

Siempre va a devolver 9, además, no estoy seguro del objetivo de este número aleatorio en la función  de introducir la apuesta.

En cuanto a calcular la combinación ganadora, por lo que entiendo, debe reducirse a obtener una combinación de 7 números aleatorios dentro de cierto rango.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que deben ser números enteros entre 1 y 49. Esta podría ser una solución.

```
public bool disponible(int numero, int[] tomados){
   for(int i = 0; i < tomados.length; i++){
      if(numero == tomados[i]){
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

public int[] calcularCombinacionGanadora(){
   int [] combinacion=new int[7];
   //Inicializando el array
   for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
      combinacion[i] = -1;
   }
   //Rellenando el array
   for(int i=0; i < 6; i++){
      numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
      while(!disponible(numero, combinacion)){
         numero = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
      }
      combinacion[i] = numero;
   }
   combinacion[6] = (int)(Math.random() * 10)
   return combinacion;
}
```

Comment: cuando hago el reintegro me sale un numero mayor a 9 y el ejercicio tiene que ser de 0 a 9 y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la función Math.random() retorna un numero aleatorio entre 0 y 1 (con el 0 incluido, pero sin incluir al 1), por ejemplo 0.2318, 0.00, 0.1298, 0.0235, etc. Si lo multiplicamos por 9, por ejemplo, obtendremos numeros entre 0 y 9 (sin incluir al nueve). Por ejemplo, si necesitas un numero de 0 a 9, ambos incluidos, haz algo asi (int)(Math.random() * 10)

Comment: Hago lo que me dices pero yo quiero que salga 7 numeros del 1 al 49 aleatorios y el reintegro del 0 al 9

Comment: A que te refieres con el reintegro?

Comment: Que en el ejercicio me sale esto mira te pongo un ejemplo: 34 21 23 12 1 5 Reintegro: 34 yo lo que quiero es que se mantenga lo de la izquierda y el reintegro entre el 0 y el 9

Comment: Que se mantenga el 3 y se sustituya el 4 por un número entre 0 y 9? En el 34 digo.

Comment: Solo numero del 0 al 9 en el reintegro

Comment: Ok, ya entendi, espera un momento y edito la respuesta

Comment: Muchas Gracias , Me funcionó , Te lo agradezco

Comment: Que bueno, ese es el objetivo. Considera votar y aceptar la respuesta y así le puede ser útil a otros.